# On scroll change class Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**HTML**

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-content>
    <div #scrolledToElement class="second-block" [ngClass]="flag ? 'red' : 'green' "></div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

**CSS**

```
.second-block {
  margin-bottom: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, VERSION, HostListener, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Ionic 6.2 Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  constructor() {}

  flag = false;
  @ViewChild("scrolledToElement", { static: false })
  scrolledToElement: ElementRef;
  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
  onScroll(event) {
    if (window.scrollY > this.scrolledToElement.nativeElement.offsetTop) {
      this.flag = true;
      console.log("flag", this.flag);
    }
    else
    {
      this.flag = false;
    }
  }
}
```

How to change the class on scroll?
I want a solution for the latest Angular version
stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-wsjtit?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Any solution, please?

Working URL :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhb4yw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Findex.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I tried the solution for latest Angular 14 version and it worked there. Seems like there is an issue with ion-content.

Answer (score 0):

**@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])** works fine in the web browser. As you are using ionic you need to use their custom events provided in the documentation for ion-content.

```html
  <ion-content [scrollEvents]="true"
  (ionScrollStart)="logScrollStart($event)"
       (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)" 
       (ionScrollEnd)="logScrollEnd($event)">
       
       
       
  </ion-content>
```

Implement above methods in **app.component.ts** file. You can define your change class logic **logScrolling** method. Instead of **window.scrollY** use **event.detail.scrollTop** from the event provided by ionScroll.

```js
logScrollStart(event) {
    console.log("logScrollStart : When Scroll Starts", event);
 }

 logScrolling(event) {
    console.log("logScrolling : When Scrolling", window.scrollY);
    console.log("Offset", this.scrolledToElement.nativeElement.offsetTop);
    if (event.detail.scrollTop > this.scrolledToElement.nativeElement.offsetTop) {
      this.flag = true;
      console.log('flag', this.flag);
    } else {
      this.flag = false;
    }
 }

 logScrollEnd(event) {
    console.log("logScrollEnd : When Scroll Ends", event);
 }
```

Here is the forked [stackblitz repository](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-ucyfdg?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: It's saying: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'offsetTop')

Any Solution!

Comment: In the stackblitz it is working. You need to define scrollToElement in the component.